# How to define pattern

Tags: c, file, design-patterns

I have  data files in which the information is the same but in different columns. E.g

Year Month Time Value.

From different source I have the same type of information but columns are for example:

Value, Time, Month, Year.

Now my question. How can I keep this info in arrays of the same name: year, month e.t.c. I should mention that at the beginning I can define which column is what.

Comment: If the data has column headings you can explore them and and make a translation from the input data's column number, to your program's array of data.

Comment: Is soemone hacking the site? Evdery comment I make, after a few seconds I try to edit and all is see is [object Object] and not the text I typed.

Comment: Good question for meta. I expect it was a legit code change by the SO crew that has a bug.

Comment: @Kris_Holder you can do this with a lookup table for each file to convert the column number if you already know the arrangement of the data. If you don't already know, and column headings are provided, you can create a lookup for the file.